# New AWS Amplify withAuthenticator error related to maplibre-gl-js-amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-amplify, maplibre-gl

NPM recommended I upgrade aws-amplify to the latest version yesterday, which I did. I then started a new React project in a dev environment (using "npm start"). The package.json file indicates these dependency versions:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^2.15.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.18",
    "maplibre-gl-js-amplify": "^1.4.1",
    ... (other irrelevant dependencies removed for this example)
  },
```

Upon calling the line below:

```
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
```

I get 12 similar errors of the same issue. Here is one such error:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react/node_modules/maplibre-gl-js-amplify/lib/esm/AmplifyMapLibreGeocoder.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\projects\amplify-project\node_modules\@aws-amplify\ui-react\node_modules\maplibre-gl-js-amplify\src\AmplifyMapLibreGeocoder.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\projects\amplify-project\node_modules\@aws-amplify\ui-react\node_modules\maplibre-gl-js-amplify\src\AmplifyMapLibreGeocoder.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react/node_modules/maplibre-gl-js-amplify/lib/esm/index.js 3:0-86 6:0-134 6:0-134
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react/dist/esm/components/Geo/MapView/index.js 5:0-69 35:16-17
 @ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react/dist/esm/index.js 13:0-60 13:0-60
 @ ./src/App.js 9:0-58
 @ ./src/index.js 8:0-24 16:33-36
```

**maplibre-gl-js-amplify** is a dependency, though not one I am even using.

I notice in the error that it's referencing the "C:\projects\amplify-project\node_modules@aws-amplify\ui-react\node_modules\maplibre-gl-js-amplify\src" directory.

However, when I navigate to "C:\projects\amplify-project\node_modules@aws-amplify\ui-react\node_modules\maplibre-gl-js-amplify", **there IS no src directory**!

The "C:\projects\amplify-project\node_modules@aws-amplify\ui-react\node_modules\maplibre-gl-js-amplify" directory only has **dist** and **lib** directories.

When researching, I looked at the github repo and see there is a **src** directory but no **dist** or **lib** directories, with different files in the file structure:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/maplibre-gl-js-amplify

I don't know if the recent changes to aws-amplify caused this new issue or not but bottom line is, it appears that Amplify is calling resources in the **src** directory erroneously, or is referencing the development version of this repo and not the distribution version.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix?

Comment: hi @arion-gnotta, I had the same issue as well when using the `withAuthenticator`. you can fix it by adding `mapbox-gl` module to your project `npm i mapbox-gl`

Comment: it's a known issue https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/issues/1647

Comment: At the very least, upgrading to version 2.15.2 should lower your bundle size, but possibly still show warnings or errors.